# Union of two loops in the toric code is a loop?

Tags: quantum-information, topology, quantum-computer, anyons

In the [toric code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toric_code) , configurations of the vertex operator $\sum_v A_v=\sum_v\sigma^z \otimes \sigma^z \otimes \sigma^z\otimes \sigma^z$ with eigenvalue $+1$ form closed loops of $|1\rangle$ states where $\sigma^z |1\rangle=-|1\rangle$. For example, if we represent the $|1\rangle$ state by a red line, the following configuration has eigenvalue $+1$:

[image]

My question is about the following configuration, given by the union of two loops:

[image]

If we apply the vertex operator to the two vertices marked in blue we get an eigenvalue $-1$ for $A_v$. Then, in principle, we violate the claim that closed loops have eigenvalue $+1$. I attended a lecture where the professor said that the link between the two vertices in blue should be removed and one would have only one closed loop. But I do not understand why it should be removed, after all it is a allowed configuration.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an allowed configuration: $A_v$ is $-1$. The "union" of two loops is really the *sum* of two loops, modulo 2. So if you add two loops on two adjacent plaquettes, you get a bigger loop, with *no* edge in the middle (in your second picture).

Comment: @Nobert Schuch, thank you very much for your answer! Just a clarification please: is it correct to say that the configuration in the second picture is an allowed configuration, although it has $A_v=-1$ ? I mean, it is a allowed configuration in general, it is not just an allowed configuration for $A_v=+1$. Not sure if I was clear :P

Comment: Also, can we then say that the configuration in the second picture is not a closed loop? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yes, it is allowed in the toric code (but not in a gauge theory). And yes, the loop in the second picture is not a closed loop: By definition, a closed loop is a configuration with $A_v=+1$.